# What does "on two different planes" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "on two different planes" mean in

> Behind all the fantasy of the Gothic imagination there remained, *on two different planes*, a sharp sense of reality. [Source : Barron's SAT workbook](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=HpnmZgLoU3UC&pg=PA884#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: With "does" your verb should not be in 3rd singular tense.

Comment: Something like this: https://books.google.com/books?id=HpnmZgLoU3UC&pg=PA884&dq=Behind+all+the+fantasy+of+the+Gothic+imagination+there+remained,+on+two+different+planes,+a+sharp+sense+of+reality.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJxfTw7_nMAhVI1xoKHUyXCWsQuwUIIDAA#v=onepage&q=Behind%20all%20the%20fantasy%20of%20the%20Gothic%20imagination%20there%20remained%2C%20on%20two%20different%20planes%2C%20a%20sharp%20sense%20of%20reality.&f=false

Comment: @Sina thanks, should I edit my question to add the source?

Comment: As J.R. suggested in a comment below, this is from the third episode of *[Civilisation: A Personal View by Kenneth Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilisation_%28TV_series%29)*: Romance and Reality. (You may find it on YouTube.) I haven't seen this show, so I can't say much, but it looks like it's about art appreciation, and we have many dualities in the arts, e.g., body and soul, form and substance, content and expression, and so on. I'm pretty sure it must have been one of these, but which? I can't say until I know more about Kenneth Clark. Others may be more familiar with his work.

Comment: Santi: You should [always](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) include your source.

Comment: @Santo it is a very good idea. Notice correcting your verb tense in your question.

Comment: In my idea the author's  emphasizing that "reality" and "fantasy" are at two different levels of thought. They are opposite of each other in the Gothic world.

Comment: Using this link, tera-3.ul.cs.cmu.edu/NASD/01cf394d-c0ee-4090-918f-a8413fe96bee/…, helps to understand it better

Comment: @Sina the link is not working

Comment: http://tera-3.ul.cs.cmu.edu/NASD/01cf394d-c0ee-4090-918f-a8413fe96bee/serv/data/thousand/5bf/12b/bcd/c64/c5d/e/TXT/00000089.txt

Comment: The above one works.

Comment: In this page, you can see that the part you asked is under the "fantasy and reality", as if they are compared. So two planes may mean these 2 levels of thought.

Comment: I've skimmed over the first two episodes and, really, I couldn't find anything clear about any duality (except for "both in architecture and in thought" in episode 2, which I think is unlikely for this "two planes"). In the end, I think Sina's suggestion is very plausible (even though the phrase sounds a bit odd to me; it's like saying "a sharp sense of reality remained behind all the fantasy on both the fantasy plane and on the reality plane", which is a bit illogical, IMO). So I guess it's fantasy and reality as Sina's suggested or as in the episode title itself: *Romance and Reality*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plane** here is used in its alternative meaning of **level**.
You could replace:

> On two different **planes**.

With:

> On two different **levels**.

Though I can't really say more about it without the previous and following sentences.

Comment: You can see the surrounding context by looking [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Behind+all+the+fantasy+of+the+Gothic+imagination+there+remained%2C+on+two+different+planes%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). It looks like it's taken from Chapter 3 of _Civilisation_ by Kenneth Clark, but I suspect the OP ran across it in the Barron's SAT prep book.

Comment: @J.R. how did you know? :-/